# Getting wrong data from parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse with their email authentication service. The user which does not click on the link sent to his email id will have a false value under the emailVerified column. So, I wrote a code to check whether this value is true or false.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    Boolean authenticationValue = currentUser.getBoolean("emailVerified");
    Log.i(TAG, "The Boolean Value is :"+authenticationValue);
    Log.i(TAG, "The current user is :" + currentUser.getUsername());

    if(currentUser != null)
    {
        if (authenticationValue) {
            Log.i(TAG, currentUser.getUsername());
        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotAuthenticated.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        takeToLogin();
    }
```

I checked the value before clicking on that link, and the value was false as expected. But, after I clicked on that link, I am still getting the false value.

I have checked my dashboard on Parse and it say that it is true. So, what is the mistake in this code.

Comment: U could catch an NPE at least here `Log.i(TAG, "The current user is :" + currentUser.getUsername());` since u check currentUser for null later

Comment: Whats the reason for using wrapper here: `Boolean authenticationValue = ...`? instead of `boolean authenticationValue = ...`

Comment: And the last: what `Log.i(TAG, "The Boolean Value is :"+authenticationValue);` outputs?

Comment: The last one shows the "false" value, while it is "true" !!

Comment: And why are you so SURE its true?

Comment: may be this helps https://parse.com/questions/updating-the-currentuser-in-android as Parse.getCurrentUser() uses local copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after searching for a while. The app uses a local database instead of fetching it from Parse every time. So, we have to force the app to fetch the updated data.
So, it can be done using the below method.

```
 ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
 currentUser.fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                boolean value = parseObject.getBoolean("emailVerified");
                Log.i(TAG, "The Value is :"+value);
            } else {
                // Failure!
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: is it recommended to call fetchInBackground everytime the app opens?

Answer (score 0):

Again: try to use `boolean` instean of wrapped `Boolean` as follows:

```
boolean authenticationValue = Boolean.valueOf(currentUser.getString("emailVerified").toString());
```

and I'm pretty sure you'll get a NPE. And if I'm right (u have to check it) then the only thing here to think about is why are you getting an NPE. Actually hidden NPE is the reason why your `Boolean` `authenticationValue` is `false`. I'm prefer u to think :)
Here is the hint:

```
Log.i(TAG, "The emailVerified Value is: "+currentUser.getString("emailVerified"));
```

if that log outputs null then there is no value "emailVerified" in currentUser. Try to log the whole currentUser object maybe it has toString() and thus u'll be able to see al the data it contains:

```
Log.i(TAG, "The currentUser is: "+String.valueOf(currentUser));
```

Could you also log the available keys:

```
Log.i(TAG, "The currentUser is: "+currentUser.keySet());
```

Comment: Hey Stan, While using the first line you provided, I did get a NPE. I put that line after the if statement where it check whether the currentUser is null or not. But still it gave me an NPE. After that I added the last line you provided. Now my code look like this http://s1.postimg.org/ccz1efenj/Capture2.png

Comment: I have checked on Parse the value of emailVerified and there is the screenshot for that http://s24.postimg.org/bsrtazwlh/Capture1.png  and here is the snapshot of the logcat http://s9.postimg.org/8d4xqh8e7/Capture3.png

Comment: You see - I was right. The log (at capture3) returns null. How `null` could be `true`? Can u see whats the problem? Your currentUser does NOT HAVE any emailVerified value at all. thats why you gettin' null

Comment: But I have pasted the screenshot of the parse dashboard and it is true. So, why it is giving the null value?

Comment: The currentUser does not have any emailVerified value at all. Maybe, I don't know, just maybe, emailVerified is not emailVerified but isEmailVerified. Could you log the currentUser itself? Log.i(TAG, "The currentUser is: "+currentUser);

Comment: I have logged the currentUser and it is giving com.parse.ParseUser@5280bdb8 and I also logged the value using "EmailVerified" and its still giving null.

Comment: I have logged the currentUser using the last statement in your answer and it is giving com.parse.ParseUser@5280bdb8 and I also logged the value using "EmailVerified" and its still giving null.